# Why am I getting more rows that I expect when joining 5 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

We are using the following query to join 5 tables. It is working fine up to 4 tables and gives the result properly, but after adding item table its giving more rows then required as it takes item name for all the orders.

```
SELECT
    CMP.CMPName, 
    OrderHeader.ID, 
    OrderHeader.Date,
    Customer.Name, 
    OrderDetail.Qty, 
    ItemMaster.ItemName
FROM OrderHeader 
INNER JOIN CMP ON Orders.CompanyID=Company.ID 
INNER JOIN Customer ON OrderHeader.CustomerID=Customer.ID 
INNER JOIN OrderDetail ON OrderHeader.OrderID=OrderDetail.OrderHeaderID   
INNER JOIN ItemMaster ON OrderDetail.ItemID=ItemMaster.ID;
```

Comment: Some sample input and expected output along with table structure would be nice.

Comment: CMP having 1 Record with ID ane Name, Cusomer having 1 Record with ID and Name, OrderHeader haing 1 record with ID , Date and CustomerID, OrderDetails having 2 Records with OrderHeaderID, ItemID and Qty, and StockItem having 2 Records with ID and NAme

Comment: if i joint upto 4 tables it gives result of 2 Records but after joint 5th Table it gives result of 4 Records

Comment: We have tried Left Join also but it gives the same result

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information, rather than trying to put it in the comments.

Comment: it might be the value of your foreign key does not have associated records in another table, provide a sample data and expected output for us to look what's wrong than imagining things

Comment: sorry it was duplicate records in Table because of which it was giving error

Comment: do you have indexes on foreign keys? It might help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to check if all the fields of

```
OrderDetail.ItemID
```

or

```
ItemMaster.ID;
```

are distinct ore have empty values.
joining two fields with empty values produces non reliable results.

Comment: sorry it was duplicate records in Table because of which it was giving error